# IDE like system - Database or Filesystem for Storage

Tags: mysql, sql, ide, filesystems

The project is an  open source **IDE like system to edit code, alter images,**, run code, etc. for students in school.

It contains an upload of Archive/Folders which characteristics are:

- Upload Archive, contains up to 30 files (txt,js,xul,xml,php, gif/png/jpg), av.size in total 500kb
- Users can edit and fork
- all the files are editable through Codemirror (like used on jsfiddle)
- *all the Gif/Png/Jpg are replaceable (10 - 40 per archive)*
- we expect daily at least 1'000 new uploads/forks with an average of 20 files, total-size min. 500 mb

**Our enironment:**

- PHP
- most likely MySQL database
- Linux

**To consider:**

- We **don't** require Searching through the folders/files on global scope
- the User saved Data is as it is, never any changes from our side necessary

**State-of-Development:**

- Ready besides the storage question and all their dependencies

**Would you advise on SQL or a simple Filesystem?**

Before starting the project we were 100% sure using MySQL, but with the added feature of Image modification and a growing database (atm 80/k files,2GB) we struggle. Also reading [here](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525) let us hesitate too.

Advantages of MYSQL are surely the easy maintainment and simpler future restructure of the system.
Though it will get a huge database fast to search within.

By using a global php entryfile to read the Filesystem based on URL parameters, the searching can be ommitted and straight go displaying the fetched directory with its content.

We are not experienced in managing large data and rely on experience of people who faced such a situtation already.

Rather than just vote for Database or Filesystem please **consider your own tips to make this environment more efficient to run** (eg [indexing](http://techdigger.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/creating-indexes-sorting-very-large-tables-fast-mysql/), structure, tables, etc..) or elaborate your decision.

very thankful for any tips of you

*btw, the project will be hosted at git*

Comment: Questions of whether to keep files (in particular images) in the DBMS or on the filesystem are asked and discussed regularly on SO. General bias is towards the file system as the one better suited for file storage.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp yes. our basic stress test for a DB involved mapping directorytructure to xml and than saving that along with the filecontent and imagepaths to DB. Compared to a Filesystem its 40% slower, tested on 80'000 rows, 2gb mem. We likely will go with the filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the best option to go is the file system taking into consideration your requirements. The pros of this choice are

1. Better performance of your database since the table will only hold a link to your file system where the file is stored.
2. It is easier to backup your database.
3. You have the possibility of storing the files in different locations by defining rules. This gives you a flexibility in managing your storage.

When we faced a similar problem for storing attachments in a service desk application, we have chosen to go with the filesystem. Till now everything is working as expected.

I hope that my answer is helpful to you.